# Mutlithreading with raw PyMySQL for celery

Tags: python, mysql, flask, celery, pymysql

In the project I am currently working on, I am not allowed to use an ORM so I made [my own](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/tree/dev/backend/PyMatcha/utils/orm)

It works great but I am having problems with Celery and it's concurrency. For a while, I had it set to `1` (using `--concurrency=1`) but I'm adding [new tasks](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/pull/342) which take more time to process than they need to be run with celery beat, which causes a huge backlog of tasks.

When I set celery's concurrency to > 1, here's what happens (pastebin because it's big):

https://pastebin.com/M4HZXTDC

Any idea on how I could implement some kind of lock/wait on the other processes so that the different workers don't cross each other?

Edit: Here is where I setup my [PyMySQL instance](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/blob/9031e8b73968edc631e516772462e6600515c0c8/backend/PyMatcha/__init__.py#L133-L148) and how the [open and close are handled](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/blob/9031e8b73968edc631e516772462e6600515c0c8/backend/PyMatcha/utils/orm/_model.py#L177-L180)

Comment: Well they should be doing that, but it seems that they do it at the same time, or there is something I didn't understand in the way I setup my PyMySQL

Comment: I see this in the code: `database_uri=f"sqlite:///{BACKEND_ROOT}/../chatbot_database.sqlite3",`

Comment: Looks like the database connection is done only in the Flask app. I have no idea if Celery tasks can use it. Best would be to grab those connection details, and open DB session inside a task, do DML and close it. I am sure Flask users will know what the issue is...

Comment: What you saw is linked to something else and not part of the error. This is a local sqlite database, and not used by flask but by celery only and not causing the error. The error is caused when multiple threads try to read/write to the DB at the same time

Comment: you have two workers and they are using the same network connection, and that will never work, so every instance need their own

Comment: In that case should I change my db connection setup to some kind of function/factory so that the workers have a separate one ?

Comment: @nbk So I tried creating my `pymysql.connect(**database_config)` in a function so the worker would have it's own but I still have the same error

Comment: try https://github.com/jkklee/pymysql-pool multithreading is a complex handling, with concurrency and their problems. also what you always need is semaphores https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio-sync.html to en capsule critical sections

Comment: Thank you for pymysql-pool, it's actually what I was trying before I saw your reply. I cannot get it to work right now but I'll keep trying.

Comment: @juleslasne Have you tried using sessions? 
https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/13/orm/contextual.html
each time you need to close the session, seems like number of connections you are openineg is not being accepted by MySQL.

Comment: @arshpreet Sadly on this project I am not allowed to use an ORM, so I had to make my own...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PyMSQL does not allow threads to share the same connection (the module can be shared, but threads cannot share a connection). Your Model class is [reusing the same connection](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/blob/feature/chatbot/backend/PyMatcha/utils/orm/_model.py#L10-L18) everywhere.

So, when different workers call on the models to do queries, they are using the same connection object, causing conflicts.

Make sure your connection objects are thread-local. Instead of having a `db` class attribute, consider a method that will retrieve a thread-local connection object, instead of reusing one potentially created in a different thread.

For instance, [create your connection in the task](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53594951/5747944).

Right now, you're using a global connection everywhere for every model.

```py
# Connect to the database
connection = pymysql.connect(**database_config)


class Model(object):
    """
    Base Model class, all other Models will inherit from this
    """

    db = connection
```

To avoid this you can create the DB in the `__init__` method instead...

```py
class Model(object):
    """
    Base Model class, all other Models will inherit from this
    """

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.db = pymysql.connect(**database_config)
```

However, this may not be efficient/practical because every instance of the db object will create a session.

To improve upon this, you could use an approach using [`threading.local`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data) to keep connections local to threads.

```py
class Model(object):
    """
    Base Model class, all other Models will inherit from this
    """
    _conn = threading.local()
    @property
    def db(self):
        if not hasattr(self._conn, 'db'):
            self._conn.db = pymysql.connect(**database_config)
        return self._conn.db
```

Note, a thread-local solution works assuming you're using a threading concurrency model. Note also that celery uses multiple processes (prefork) by default. This may or may not be a problem. If it is a problem, you may be able to work around it if you [change the workers to use eventlet](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/concurrency/eventlet.html) instead.

Comment: Oh I see ! I'll try this and let you know how it goes

Comment: I've awarded you the +rep bounty because it would've gone to waste, even though I haven't solved my problem yet. I'm still trying to figure out how to implement thread safe DB connection and all...

Comment: I think it would help alot if you moved [this line](https://github.com/Seluj78/PyMatcha/blob/feature/chatbot/backend/PyMatcha/utils/orm/_model.py#L19) inside of `__init__` and created a new connection every time `self.db = pymysql.connect(**database_config)` Or. You may also find it useful to take advantage of Pythons [thread-local data](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#thread-local-data) interfaces for optimization (only create a connection once for each thread, instead of every model object)

Comment: Thank you so much for the edit of your answer, the `db` property worked !! Now it's just a matter of optimizing the task that takes a while but other than that, it's flawless! Thank you so much ! I did have to use `--pool=threads` for it to work !